# Cocos2d and chipmunk how to simulate depth?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, simulate, depth

I am developing a game that intends to toss an object but instead of having it being tossed horizontally I would like to simulate it being thrown along the imaginary z axis that is simulate depth in my game. Something like the nintendo duck hunt game. Can someone point me in the right direction to implement this?. My first idea was to implement a series of "floors" to rest the object and making the object progressively smaller and applying a force to the object along the y axis. Is this anything close to a possible approach for this?. I have never done anything like this before. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

-Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far as I can see you're trying to simulate 3d, using a 2d engine.

If it doesn't have to be very complex, you could approximate it by changing the size of your sprite over time. That could work (poorly) for simple ballistics.

Comment: It works, but then how to simulate one sprite getting behind another?